# Extract to multiple list in one line for loop

Tags: python

I have a tabular data like follow and want to extract to data of each individual columns

```
data = [
    {'id': 1, 'val': 'A'},
    {'id': 3, 'val': 'C'},
    {'id': 2, 'val': 'B'},
    {'id': 7, 'val': 'E'},
    {'id': 1, 'val': 'G'},
]
list_id = [item['id'] for item in data ]
list_val = [item['val'] for item in data ]
```

Or simply just:

```
for item in data:
    list_id.append(item['id'])
    list_val.append(item['val'])
```

However, May I know there is a way of **one line** like this ?

```
list_id, list_val = [item['id'], item['val'] for item in data]
```

Thanks a lot.
Alex

Comment: are you looking for `zip(item['id'], item['val'])`?

Comment: Can you share the detail ? I would like to get the all single columns data in one line

Comment: No. It's not duplicated since my question is very specific in ONE LINE solution

Comment: The most upvoted answer there contains two one-liner solutions: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39441390/7851470).

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this could work (don't know if it's the best solution):

```
list_id, list_val = zip(*list(map(lambda x: (x['id'], x['val']), data)))
```

The line above returns tuples, for returning lists add another map:

```
list_id, list_val = map(list, zip(*list(map(lambda x: (x['id'], x['val']), data))))
```

Comment: Yes it's work. May be the best solution until now